# Detect whether a subclass has called a parent class

Tags: php

Suppose i call the parent class of my subclass with `parent::__construct();` .How can i detect whether the parent class have been called by a subclass in the parent class

Comment: a `private static` variable accessed only from the parent''s constructor? It would not be accessed or overriden, as it's `private`

Comment: I think you want to have a look at [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace). Afaik it's the only way to "detect" where a function / method call is coming from.

Comment: It might be helpful if you explain why you need to do this. Without explanation it sounds a bit like your modelling might be a bit off if you need to do this, but am sure there's a good reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question but my suggestion is to set a static variable that's `true`, in my case `$CHILD`, in the **Child class** then use `get_called_class` in the **Parent class** and then test the aforementioned static variable.

```
class Base {

    public function __construct() {
        $child = get_called_class();
        if($child::$CHILD)
        {
            echo "Parent has being called";
        }
    }
}

class Child extends Base {

    public static $CHILD = true;

    public function __constructor()
    {
        parent::__constructor();
    }
}

$child = new Child();
```

Another approach would be to use debug_backtrace as @icecub suggested

Comment: This answers the question, but it's pretty grim code / design. Base classes should not be concerning themselves with whether, what by or how they've being extended. You sure you wanna be encouraging practice like this? A better approach would have been to tease more out from the OP so we can understand why they think they have this requirement. Downvoting on this basis.

Comment: Why or what the person asking the wants to do with the answer is none of my business and neither should it be your. This is Q&A forum, not tuturial site. BTW, the person asking doesn't seem to be a novice to me. Next time just answer the question then offer advice. @AdamCameron

Comment: No need to get snippy fella. I think the OP def *is* a OO journeyman if they're asking a question framed like this. Perhaps not, but that's how it *seems* given the question. Sometimes - *often* even - when someone asks a question, they're not asking the question they mean to be asking, and it takes some effort to tease this out. Ultimately we're here to *help people*, not just blindly "answer questions because it's a Q&A site", and helping them sometimes means a bit of back and forth first.

Comment: Correction noted @AdamCameron